# Change the frequency of AC voltage from 60 Hz to 2 Hz

Tags: voltage, ac, frequency

I have Alternating Current 208 V single phase at 60 Hz and need to change it to Alternating Current 30 V at 2 Hz.

How would I do this?

This is for a plating application.

Comment: Rectify and invert.

Comment: I smell an XY problem here. Surely you are not going to plate something with 2Hz 30V AC

Comment: More details please. WHY 2 Hz. Why 30V. Who says?What power / current?  Sine or square & does it matter. Links? The 208-> 30V is easy enough. A transformer can handle that. The 2 Hz is harder and knowing more about why and what for and ...? may save you some expense.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Find (or build) a DC coupled audio amplifier of appropriate power rating, and feed it from a signal generator set to 2 Hz.

Answer (score 2):

According to the information given to the answer with links in a [**question**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35455/using-ac-voltage-for-electroplating) in the chemistry stack exchange, you probably don't want AC, but rather pulsed DC. The pulses can be all of one polarity or both positive and negative, but the positive and negative voltages are not equal. If you want to design a power conversion circuit to do that, you should first define the waveform completely including the voltage, current, pulse width, pulse frequency and range of adjustment. Then do some research on power conversion circuit design.

You may be able to buy a packaged plating power supply. A VFD is not appropriate for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the request rather than validating whether it is the correct request...

since the frequency is lower you could consider a cycloconverter. With the frequency of interest < 10% of the supply the resultant waveform will be quite good.

[image]

They are very simple and basically just run.

Answer (score -3):

Use a tranformer.  I don't know why you need 2Hz, but a tranformer will get you down to the 30v you require.  It sounds like you're getting power straight from the socket.  I'd like to say you know what you're doing, but be careful anyways.